# Xamarin.Forms netstandard project broken with update to VS 2017.3

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

So today i made the mistake of updating my IDE to 2017.3.

I was then notified of incompatibilities such as

"NU1202: The package Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.247 is not compatible with netstandard1.5. Package supports: *list of targets such as monoandroid10, xamarinios10, etc*"

After investigating the matter on google i found some information to try fix the project.

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/2647#issuecomment-265927440 suggests adding a frameworkmoniker to get it to build (At some point during fix attempts i had a platform warning too)

Another attempt i've made to fix the issue was recreating the project as a fresh template version of using a netstandard project (the project i've provided for repro was created during the time when project.json was still a thing)

You may ask why:  While looking for the issue i read that some are false positive error messages, which can be disabled like this [Package Reference Warning Ignore](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1335#issuecomment-309069340) - However in this project type which is entirely based on .csproj again i was unable to add Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.247.

#### So my question is:

Has anyone been able to get a similar project running on vs2017.3 yet?

#### REPRO project:

[GitHub](https://github.com/devsolvum/Vs2017.3-CompileIssue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After changing my project similar to a result of this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard1.5</TargetFramework>
        <PackageTargetFallback>portable-net45+win8+wpa81+wp8</PackageTargetFallback>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="App.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
      </EmbeddedResource>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="MainPage.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
      </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility" Version="1.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="2.3.4.247" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Update="App.xaml.cs">
        <DependentUpon>App.xaml</DependentUpon>
      </Compile>
      <Compile Update="MainPage.xaml.cs">
        <DependentUpon>MainPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
      </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

the project compiled again.

```
<PackageTargetFallback>portable-net45+win8+wpa81+wp8</PackageTargetFallback>
```

fixed the issue.